# How can I overcome the set_fact variable for one host in multiple groups

Tags: python, yaml, ansible, ansible-2.x

Inventory File

```
[dev:vars]
dev6
dev7

[dev6]
targethost1.xyz.com
[dev7]
targethost1.xyz.com
```

host_variables.yml

```
dev6:
  deploy_domain: "Dev6Domain"
  WL_Admin: "DEV6WLAdmin"
  WL_Managed: "DEV6Managed"

dev7:
  deploy_domain: "Dev7Domain"
  WL_Admin: "Dev7WLAdmin"
  WL_Managed: "Dev7Managed"
```

The command I am trying to extract the myenv.deploy_domain from the playbook by using

```
tasks:
- include_vars: host_variables.yml
- set_fact:
    my_env: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname][group_names[1]] }}"
```

The dev6 and dev7 share the same host but with different domain and different other variables as defined in host_variables.yml. So when I run the playbook for dev7, the my_env.deploy_domain shows me the value of dev6. How do I tell this piece of code to take only variables for current environment in play and match its specific hostname in the inventory?

Comment: targethost1.xyz.com is not a domain, its a complete hostname. deploy_domain is a variable (parameter) for deployments into each machine.

Comment: Ansible won't run the same playbook twice against the same host, no matter how many inventory groups it is a member of. You'd have to user a different hostname and point it to the same IP address in `/etc/hosts` or DNS.

Comment: Otherwise you should rewrite your playbooks to use lists instead of variables with conflicting names.

Answer (score 0):

```
[dev:vars]
dev6
dev7

[dev6]
dev6host ansible_ssh_host=targethost1.xyz.com
[dev7]
dev7host ansible_ssh-host=targethost1.xyz.com
```

Now, the with the same host being shared for different environments, ansible treats all of them as seperate machines